# Unable to open any URL in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I am encountering a strange issue in Chrome after receiving the latest update. Wherever I enter any URL such as youtube.com nothing happens no error nothing, just the page does not load.

Here is what I already tried

Uninstalled Chrome
Run a repair from control panel
delete the file local state under users/user/appdata/local/google/chrome/user data
Signed out of the browser
delete the file name master_preferences under c/program files/google/chrome/application
Installed an older version

But unfortunately unable to load any URL, also I did check the console logs and there are no data at all, neither 200 or 204

The funny fact is that it works if I do the following

Open in Incognito or lunch Chrome in compatibility mode and select Windows 8

The version I am running is 106.0.5249.91

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Manage to get it sorted by deleting the following folder: "C:\Users\useraccount\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"

Answer (score 0):

Manage to get it sorted by deleting the following folder: "C:\Users\useraccount\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"